# Redirect to differnent URL and load a javascript file

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a project  - When the URL to my site  ([www.mywebsite.com](http://www.mywebsite.com)), is entered, I want it to go automatically go to a different website in the same browser window and then go another website ([www.anotherWebsiteOne.com](http://www.anotherWebsiteOne.com)) in the same and the after X seconds will load another webSite ([www.anotherWebSiteTwo.com](http://www.anotherWebSiteTwo.com)) in the same browser, and so on.

I would like everytthing to stay in the same browser window

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

   <title>Basic Javascript Example</title>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="webSites.js"></script>
   
</head>

<body onload="start()">  

</body>

</html>
```

and my webSites.js:

```
var webSites = [
    'http://www.anotherWebPageOne.com/',
    'https://www.anotherWebPageTwo.com/',
    'http:www.anotherWebPageThree.com/',
];

var iTarget;

function nextTarget(){
    window.open( targets[iTarget], 'target' );
    if( ++iTarget >= targets.length ) {
        iTarget = 0;
    }
}

function start() {
    iTarget = 0;
    nextTarget();
    setInterval( nextTarget, 5000 );
}

start()
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use :

```
<body onload="start()">  

</body>
```

or you can simply add start() to the end of your js file

Comment: Thanks Amir - this worked, I have made anl edit to my op..any help would be great

Answer (score 0):

just add `start()` to end of your webSites.js file

whatever in your js file will be executed automatically and you have to just call the start function in the js file by invoking it.

also, rename your webSites variable to targets.

Answer (score 0):

in your JS file you just need to add `window.onload = <Your Function Name>;`
eg:-

```
var webSites = [
    'http://www.anotherWebPageOne.com/',
    'https://www.anotherWebPageTwo.com/',
    'http:www.anotherWebPageThree.com/',
];

var iTarget;

function nextTarget(){
    window.open( targets[iTarget], 'target' );
    if( ++iTarget >= targets.length ) {
        iTarget = 0;
    }
}

window.onload = nextTarget;

function start() {
    iTarget = 0;
    nextTarget();
    setInterval( nextTarget, 5000 );
}
```

I hope it will solve your problem

Comment: Thanks Sukarna, but this did not work - no page loaded.

Comment: Try out this :- ```window.onload = function(){
  // your code here
};```